# Как в Switch ограничить кликабельную область только у переключателя?

Tags: java, android, android-switch

`Switch`:

```
android:id="@+id/sw_print_receipts"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="@dimen/base_item_height"

android:text="@string/receipt_printers"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня кликабельная область у всего свичера, куда бы не кликнул (рис (1)). Как сделать так, чтобы кликабельным был только переключатель (рис (2))?

Comment: сделайте свитч без текста, а текст размещайте в текствью рядом с ним

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучшее решение – писать текст в отдельном `TextView`.

Но, если Вы уж очень хотите, то можно ограничить кликабельную область только переключателем:

```
mSwitch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Rect thumbRect = mSwitch.getThumbDrawable().getBounds();
        return !thumbRect.contains((int) motionEvent.getX(), (int) motionEvent.getY());
    }
});
```

Здесь, при клике по `Switch` запрашивается область, в которой размещен переключатель и далее происходит проверка: если клик совершен вне переключателя, то возвращается `true` и клик считается *обработанным*, в противном случае вызывается дефолтное поведение `Switch`.